# WP ACF Как выводить только выбранные элементы checkbox полей

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Подскажите, пожалуйста как выводить ключи-значения только выбранных элементов [чекбоксов](https://acfwp.ru/checkbox/)

Вот мой код

```
<div>
 <?php
   $countries = get_field_object('supported_countries', $postID);

    var_dump($countries);

      if( $countries['choices'] ): ?>
         <ul>
          <?php foreach( $countries['choices'] as $value => $label ) : ?>
            <li class="country <?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Отчего-то он выводит не только ключь-значение выбранных чекбоксов, а все что были выбраны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно это исправить. Что б в ['choices'] были только выбранные поля ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если у вас в настройках выбрано возвращаемое значение `array`, то это можно сделать вот так

```
<div>
   <?php
   $countries = (array) get_field('supported_countries', $postID);
   if( $countries ): ?>
      <ul>
         <?php foreach( $countries as $country ) : ?>
            <li class="country <?php echo $country['value']; ?>">
               <?php echo $country['label']; ?>
            </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

если в качестве возвращаемого значения выбрано `value`, то вывод будет выглядеть вот так:

```
<div>
   <?php
   $countries = get_field_object('supported_countries', $postID);
   if( $countries['value'] ): ?>
      <ul>
         <?php foreach( $countries['value'] as $country_value ) : ?>
            <li class="country <?php echo $country_value; ?>">
               <?php echo $countries['choices'][ $country_value ]; ?>
            </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```